# WooCommerce - set session with new cart item meta when updating cart item quantity

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, session

I'm trying to add meta data to cart items based on their quantity. It works all fine when I add the product to the cart, but I'm failing to update the cart item meta when the quantity is updated.

I tried

```
WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
WC()->cart->set_session();
```

and

```
$cart_content = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
$cart_content[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
WC()->session->set('cart', $cart_content);
```

inside this WooCommerce action. I chose this function because my meta is based on comparing old and new quantities.

```
woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update
```

But none of that worked. Anyone an idea where or how I can set the updated cart content?

---

### Example

Here just a ultra simplified version of my code. Generating the meta data is not the issue, setting it is.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', array( $this, 'update_restock_list'), 20, 4 );
public function update_restock_list( $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity, $cart ) {

    $cart_item = $cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];
    $id        = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];  
    $restock   = get_post_meta( $id, '_om_restock', true );

    if( !empty($restock) ) {      

        $diff    = abs($quantity - $old_quantity);
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $stock   = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if( $quantity > $stock ) {
            if( $quantity > $old_quantity ) {
                $cart_item['restock_info'] += $diff;
            } else {
                $cart_item['restock_info'] -= $diff;
            }
        } else {
            unset($cart_item['restock_info]);
        }
    }

    //update the cart
    $cart_content = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
    $cart_content[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
    WC()->session->set('cart', $cart_content);
    WC()->cart->set_session();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### SOLVED

This is how I did it.

Getting the cart content.

```
$cart_content = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
```

Replacing the cart item with the new updated version.

```
$cart_content[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
```

This here made the change. Setting the updated cart content.

```
WC()->cart->set_cart_contents($cart_content);
```